# How to express two columns with org-mode format to be exported by Pandoc to Powerpoint

Tags: markdown, org-mode, pandoc

With Markdown, I can format two columns in a slide with the following example:

```
# Introduction
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="60%"}
- My notes based on my partial understanding
:::
::: {.column width="40%"}
- Joined late in the project
:::
::::::::::::::
```

I wonder what would be the equivalent in org-mode format?

I understand that org-mode is not designed as markdown format. But I really want to have the benefits of both of org-mode in emacs and the power of format of markdown with Pandoc.

It would work equally well for me if I could treat markdown content in emacs as if it were an org-mode file. I found that emacs to some extent treat markdown as org-mode content in markdown mode, but it does not fold nested lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use custom blocks combined with block attributes to get the desired result.

```
#+BEGIN_columns

#+ATTR_HTML: :width 60%
#+BEGIN_column
- My notes based on my partial understanding
#+END_column

#+ATTR_HTML: :width 40%
#+BEGIN_column
- Joined late in the project
#+END_column

#+END_columns
```

Pandoc currently only reads HTML attributes and uses these for all formats.

Comment: Thanks! I put the above content into a file: scratch.org, and execute pandoc scratch.org -o scratch.pdf but got the following error: "Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Environment columns undefined." What's missing?

Comment: Please try `pandoc scratch.org -o scratch.pdf -t beamer`. I guess columns are not defined in a normal LaTeX article, but should be in a beamer presentation.

Comment: Yes, the above solution works with pandoc commands:  pandoc scratch.org -o scratch.pdf -t beamer  or  pandoc scratch.org -o scratch.pptx